# How to make an extension remember a user button press for future sessions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am currently writing an extension that will have a simple user interface with two buttons, "Find" and "Omit". The purpose of the extension is to help filter out inappropriate language from forums and whatnot.

I have the "Omit" button set to execute a simple find and replace function on click, it filters out all inappropriate words it can find on the webpage and removes them. However, if the page is refreshed, or a new browser session is started, obviously you would have to go through the process of pressing the two buttons again.

Now for the question:
Would it be possible to have the results of the "Omit" button saved permanently, or better yet, can I have the function be called continuously on that specific page after the first button press?

I would like to somehow have all of this linked to a web application with a constantly updating list of topics and words. I believe this can be done by the messaging API, but not too sure.

I am not asking for a full how to guide, however some tips and tricks that would push me into the right direction would be appreciated greatly!

I have attempted to look into pushState(), however upon closer inspection this wasn't what I was looking for at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a small understanding of chrome extensions but you should be able to use `window.localStorage`

```
const id = 'omitButton'; //set to the omit button's id
document.getElementById(id).onclick = e => {
  localStorage.omitToggled = 1 - Number(localStorage.omitToggled ?? 0); //if null set to true
};

window.onload = e => {
  if (+localStorage.omitToggled === 1) //is toggled
    filter();
};
```

If `localStorage` doesn't work look into using `chrome.storage.local`

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

For the API, check this website https://api-ninjas.com/api/profanityfilter

The request would look something like this:

```
let text = 'damn it!'
fetch({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/profanityfilter?text=' + text,
    headers: { 'X-Api-Key': 'YOUR_API_KEY'},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function ajaxError(jqXHR) {
        console.error('Error: ', jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```